# How to use `str.replace()` method on all columns in a scraped Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I'm a Python/Pandas beginner in data analysis. I am trying to import(/scrape) a table from a Wikipedia article on letter frequency, clean it, and turn it into a data frame.

Here's the code I used to turn the table into a dataframe called `letter_freq_all`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

letter_freq_all = pd.read_html('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency', header=0)[4]
letter_freq_all
```

I want to clean the data and properly format it for data analysis:

- I want to remove the square brackets with numbers from the column names and make sure there is no whitespace padding on either side
- I also want to remove the percent signs and any asterisks from each column so I can convert each of the columns to a float type.
- So far, I have unsuccessfully attempted to remove the % signs from all of the columns.

This is the code I tried:

```
letter_freq_all2 = [str.replace(i,'%','') for i in letter_freq_all]
```

Instead of getting a new dataframe that does not have any % signs, I just got a list of all the columns in letter_freq_all:

```
['Letter','French [14]','German [15]','Spanish [16]','Portuguese [17]','Esperanto  [18]','Italian[19]','Turkish[20]','Swedish[21]','Polish[22]','Dutch [23]','Danish[24]','Icelandic[25]','Finnish[26]','Czech']
```

Then I tried getting rid of the % sign in just one column:

```
letter_freq_all3 = [str.replace(i,'%','') for i in letter_freq_all['Italian[19]']]**
```

When I did this, the `str.replace` method sort of worked - I got a list which did not have any `%` signs (I was expecting to get a series).

**So, how can I get rid of the `%` sign in all of the columns in my dataframe `letter_freq_all`? Also, how can I get rid of all the brackets and extra white space padding from all of the columns? I'm guessing I might have to use the `.split()` method**

Comment: Tagged [tag:web-scraping]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most succinct way to accomplish your goal is to use the str.replace() method with regular expressions:

1) Rename columns:

```
letter_freq_all.columns = pd.Series(letter_freq_all.columns).str.replace('\[\d+\]', '').str.strip()
```

2) Replace asterisks and percent signs and convert to decimal fraction:

```
letter_freq_all.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('[%*]', '').astype(float)/100, axis=1)
```

In this case, apply() performs the str.replace() method on each column.

Learn more about regex metacharacters here:

https://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/regular-expression/metacharacter-list.php

Answer (score 2):

For data analyisys it make sense to use `float` instead of `string` entries. So you could write a function which tries to convert each entry:

```
def f(s):
    """ convert string to float if possible """
    s = s.strip()  # remove spaces at beginning and end of string
    if s.endswith('%'):  # remove %, if exists
        s = s[:-1]
    try:
        return float(s)
    except ValueError: # converting did not work
        return s  # return original string

lf2 = letter_freq_all.applymap(f)  # convert all entries
```

Answer (score 1):

Think this works. I've used panda's [broadcasting capabilities](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#matching-broadcasting-behavior) to replace values in 1 column (actually several columns) at once.

```
# Ignore first col with letters in it.
cols = letter_freq_all.columns[1:]

# Replace the columns `cols` in the DF
letter_freq_all[cols] = (
    letter_freq_all[cols]
    # Replace things that aren't numbers and change any empty entries to nan
    # (to allow type conversion)
    .replace({r'[^0-9\.]': '', '': np.nan}, regex=True)
    # Change to float and convert from %s
    .astype(np.float64) / 100
)

letter_freq_all.head()


 Letter  French [14]  German [15]  Spanish [16]  Portuguese [17]  ...
0      a      0.07636      0.06516       0.11525          0.14634   
1      b      0.00901      0.01886       0.02215          0.01043   
2      c      0.03260      0.02732       0.04019          0.03882   
3      d      0.03669      0.05076       0.05510          0.04992   
4      e      0.14715      0.16396       0.12681          0.11570
```

Comment: Thank you, meloncholy! I tried your code and it worked. :) I was wondering if you could explain more in detail how your code works. It looks like you converted all the string values with the percent signs to nan type. I guess I'm just a bit confused about how this line of code is able to convert from nan to float. I haven't really seen this syntax before

    .replace({r'[^0-9\.]': '', '': np.nan}, regex=True)

Comment: It's possible to give pandas' [replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) a dict of from (keys) and to (values) pairs. So here, I replaced anything that wasn't a number with '' in each value and, separately, replaced empty strings with `nan`. It's (kinda) equivalent to `.replace(r'[^0-9\.]', '', regex=True).replace('', np.nan)`.

Comment: Nans are of type float. I changed empty cells to floats so I could convert every cell to a float using `astype` (as I only had numbers-as-strings or nans by that point).